In Raspbian Bookworm, how to run a headless browser with audio
I have a Spotify player in JavaScript that I need to run headless in Raspian Bookworm on a RPi5. I am controlling the player using the spotipy module in python. I have both nginx and gunicorn running as system services, and everything is working when started in the GUI using VNC.
However, I need this system to be headless and have it all start up on boot. I can start a Chromium browser in headless, but no sound is produced when starting a song in the Spotify player.
Here is my service for the browser:
    [Unit]
Description=Headfull Browser Service
After=gunicorn.service nginx.service network.target
Requires=gunicorn.service nginx.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu  --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --mute-audio=false --alsa-output-device=default --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost
Restart=always
User=myuser

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I tried doing stuff with PulseAudio, but would rather not go that way. Is it possible to make this work in Chromium? Is there another easier way to run my JavaScript in headless?

if you want a program running as your user have access to the audio seat owning the sound output, you'd want to own that seat. In other words, start a user session, and start your service as user service in that :)

@MarcusMüller, thank you for the reply. That makes sense. But how do I start a user session without actually logging in? I would like to start services and scripts when the RPi powers on.
